# DIfferential equation, transforming $\sigma(t-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

$y''(t)+5y'(t)+6y(t)=\sigma(t-1), y(0)=1, y'(0)=-1$

I'm confused how I am supposed to handle $\sigma(t-1)$?

Comment: What's $\sigma$, to begin with?

Comment: As per my understanding, $\sigma$ is a constant. May be try solving making that assumption. See where you get.

Comment: In my table it says that the if f(t)=1 or $f(t)=\sigma (t)$ its transform is 1/s

Comment: @Randy: Are you sure it isn't the Dirac Delta Function, $\delta(t-1)$ or Heaviside Unit Step Function, $u(t-1)$ or a typo?

Comment: I think it is the unit step function

Comment: @Randy: Look at item **25**, https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx. The Laplace Transform of $$u(t-1) = \frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$

Comment: @Moo: you are right, I just checked from my lecture notes and he indeed used the exact same transform except it was not written in our laplace transform table. 

Thank you! :)